# Why does it use typename in "typename Operation::second_argument_type(x)"?

Tags: c++

This is the bind2nd definition:

```
 template <class Operation, class T>
    binder2nd<Operation> bind2nd (const Operation& op, const T& x)
    {
      return binder2nd<Operation>(op, typename Operation::second_argument_type(x));
    }
```

And the key word *typename* can be used to:

- In a template declaration, typename can be used as an alternative to
  class to declare type template parameters.
- Inside a declaration or a definition of a template, typename can be
  used to declare that a dependent name is a type.

So, I think typename is used to declare that Operation::second_argument_type is a type, but I want to know why we need to use typename here ?Can't we use it ? What is the advantage to use it ?

Comment: It won't work without `typename`.  The purpose is just to allow the compiler to do a few more checks on the template, and perhaps prepare a representation of the content that's able to be instantiated faster later when actual use of the template is made.

Comment: "So, I think typename *is used to declare that Operation::second_argument_type is a type*, but *I want to know why we need to use typename* here ? *Can't we use it ?*" What do you mean?

Comment: @Rubens because I think whether there is a declaration or not ,  Operation::second_argument_type is a type.

Answer (score 0):

C++ syntax depends on whether identifier is a type or not. A statement can't be parsed without that knowledge.

Normally the compiler just looks whether the identifier has been declared as type or not. However if the symbol is dependent on template parameter, the compiler can't look. So you have to tell it.

If you use

```
Operation::second_argument_type
```

and it is a type, the compilation will *fail*, because the template will already be parsed assuming it is an object and if you use

```
typename Operation::second_argument_type
```

and it is not a type, the compilation will *fail*, because the template  will already be parsed assuming it is a type.